# button not staying within div

Tags: html, css, button

I have a `<div>` and a `<button>`, but for some reason, the button will not stay in the div.

I have tried to clear the div, as well as `float: left` but it has not helped.

I have also added `padding` to the bottom of the div, but I don't think that is the solution.

My code:

```
<div class="service-text text2">  
  <p>
this is some text
  </p>
<a href="" class="button-learn centered"><i class="fa fa-credit-card" style="padding-right:10px;"></i> Learn More</a>

  </div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qt9u3/)

Comment: What are you doing rolling back and editing your question over and over again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually parent div set its height auto to its child heights, but padding you assigned to `button-learn` is causing the issue.

you just need to set `display:inline-block;` on your anchor tag

An inline-block element is placed as an inline element (on the same line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element.

```
.button-learn {
  margin: 2px;
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius:4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family:'PT Sans',helvetica;
  background: #69c773;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size: 17px !important;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/Qt9u3/12/)

Comment: you would think that padding would just expand the div, but even adding a shadow to the button shows out of the main div..

Answer (score 1):

Floating both the elements seems to do what you want, unless you want the button to be next to the text.

add these:

```
 .service-text {
     float: left;
 }
.button-learn {
    float:left;
}
```

or check: http://jsfiddle.net/Milanzor/Qt9u3/4/

Comment: what is weird if you do this

http://jsfiddle.net/Qt9u3/5/

adding a shadow on the button it happens again a little below...

Comment: I should also say that if i try to center the button like here...
http://jsfiddle.net/Qt9u3/6/

it won't move to the middle anymore

Answer (score 0):

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qt9u3/10/)

Set document height first:

```
body, html {
    height:100%
}
```

then set `.service-text` height:

```
.service-text {
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%; /* change this from auto */
    display:block;
    background-color:#34495e;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
```

and it works!! :)

**EDIT**

[**div inside another div**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qt9u3/11/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="service-text text2">
        <p>this is some text</p>
<a href="" class="button-learn centered"><i class="fa fa-credit-card" style="padding-right:10px;"></i> Learn More</a>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#parent {
    height:100%; /* remove this and everything falls out of place*/
}
.service-text {
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    background-color:#34495e;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
.service p {
    margin:0;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-right:7px;
    padding-left:15px;
    font-family:'PT Sans', 'Arial', 'Open Sans';
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:22px;
    color:white;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
}
.button-learn {
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius:4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:'PT Sans', helvetica;
    background: #69c773;
    font-size: 17px !important;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.button-learn:hover {
    color: #51A65F;
}

    </div>
</div>
```

**Explaination** : you just need to set the height of the `div` always, once you set it.....you'll get the desired view!